# Build a bijection N\{3k+2}—>N

Tags: number-theory

I am looking for a bijection from the set $\mathbb{N} \setminus \{3k+2 \mid k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ to $\mathbb{N}.$ There must be some formula that describes the bijection.

Comment: Yes, there is a formula, but it's clunky and unenlightening. You should use words to describe it instead, it's much easier to both do and understand, and you will actually learn something in the process.

Comment: I don’t know the formula. I’m asking for it

Comment: I know you don't know the formula. That is why you are here, after all. And I am telling you that formula isn't the best way to go (and I will therefore not give you one). Use words and sentences instead, and try it on your own.

Comment: Well, you must map $\{1,3,4,6,7,9,10,12,13....\}$ to $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,...\}$ so map $1\to 1;3\to 2;4\to 3;6\to 4;7\to 5; 9\to 6... etc$.  How would you describe that? Can you generalize it?  Is there an easier and/or more clever way to do it?

Comment: One thing to note is that if $m \in N\setminus \{3k+2\}$ then $m = 3s +r$ where $r = 0$ or $r = 1$.  That's two cases.  Can we split of $N$ into two types of numbers based upon whether $r= 0$ or $r= 1$.

Comment: It might seem complicated but you can do an in between step.  $n = 3s+r \to (s, r)$ and combine it with $(s,r) \to ?????$.  (where $r = 0$ or $r=1$.)

Comment: And a final hint:  Maybe $g:N \to N\setminus \{3k + 2\}$ is easier to find than $f: N\setminus\{3k + 2\} \to N$.  But if they are both bijections $g = f^{-1}$ and $f = g^{-1}$.  You can use $g$ to fin $f$.... if that is easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \setminus \{3k+2 \mid k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ defined by $f(k) = 3k/2$ if $k$ is even, and $f(k)=3(k-1)/2+1$ if $k$ is odd. This is clearly both injective and surjective, thus a bijection.

Now if you want to describe a map from $\mathbb{N} \setminus \{3k+2 \mid k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ directly (not just referring to the inverse of this map), you need to work in a similar fashion. You end up describing two different cases (whether the reminder of a number is 0 or 1 modulo 3), and you can wrap that into one (un-insightful) formula if you really want to.

If you want this $f$ here in 'one formula', use
$$
f(k)=\frac{6k-1+(-1)^k}{4}.
$$
By checking both cases ($k$ even or odd) you see that the formulas agree.

Now how do you arrive at a formula like this? I just the 'building block' $(1-(-1)^k)/2,$ which is 0 or 1 depending whether $k$ is even or odd. You can build up you formula from that and simplify.

Comment: First off, please let people try themselves before giving an answer. They come here to learn, and just giving then the solution when they haven't tried anything themselves doesn't help them, really. Second, this isn't anywhere near surjective: $f(1)=4,f(3)=10,f(4)=12$, and so on. (It hits about a fourth of all numbers as it goes.)

Comment: There was a small typo, it is surjective now.

Comment: And while it doesn't deserve a down vote any more (assuming it's correct this time), I still stand by what I said in both my previous comment, and in my two comments to the question itself: this does not help the OP. If they read this answer, and their next problem is to find a bijection between $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb N\setminus\{2k+1\}$, they have no choice but to come straight back here, because your answer teaches them _nothing_.

Comment: Thanks for the catch, it was from $\mathbb{N}$ to the set with missing $3k+2$s of course - fixed now.

Comment: @Arthur, I added a little more prose to make it hopefully slightly more useful to the OP.